# Rice Field Levee Contours - .2 foot interval needed - LiDAR data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, contour

I am a rice farmer in Arkansas and would like to create levees along contour lines in a field at a .2 foot interval. How could I utilize LiDAR data to map 0.2 foot contour intervals across my area of interest?

I got 2014 Lidar data from USGS Earth Explorer. 900 mb.

Comment: Is LiDAR data available for your area of interest, or are you planning on acquiring new data?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Unfortunately, we use a "Focused question / Best answer" model, which isn't well suited to Boolean or ternary questions (LiDAR could be used, to make a DEM, but that's only the start of the journey), or to "What software should I use?" questions (which could attract proponents of every package).  What I would suggest is looking for a tutorial or blog post about doing something similar, then trying to reproduce it, and asking a specific question if you run across a problem.

Comment: I got 2014 Lidar data from USGS Earth Explorer. 900 mb.

Comment: You've tagged this with arcgis-desktop - have you read the data into it? Does it have a contour generating option?

Comment: Its Arc... of course it can create contours... LiDAR data is variable, but in open areas a bare earth model is likely to use more points and be more detailed/accurate. You are asking for something at or near the limitations of the data most likely. All you would need to do is run Spatial Analyst Tools>Surface>Contour with an interval for your required contours and create terraces based on the contours.

Comment: When I was using 1m LIDAR in PA we could accurately get 2 ft contour lines, but your looking for .2' or 2.25" contours. That would be some very accurate LIDAR, and I'm doubting USGS would have a use for data that accurate. Their project areas are usually on a state and national level not the local parcel or field. While you could use their data to generate contours of 2" I would question the accuracy because of the data quality used.

Comment: Please clarify.  You have LiDAR of a flat field that you want to rice farm?  You do not have a levee now but you want to use ArcGIS to create a new surface model from LiDAR that has the levees you want to build?

Comment: NRCS has their LIDAR datasets by county there...https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/GDGOrder.aspx?order=QuickState

Comment: Take a look at: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203245/creating-contours-using-bare-earth-lidar-xyzi-point-data; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127751/creating-tin-and-contours-in-arcgis-for-desktop; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78592/how-to-create-contours-from-smoothed-dem-instead-of-using-terrain-to-raster.